# Iterate down a pandas series and if 1st position of string is NOT '1' then split at 1st occurrence of space to new column

Tags: python, pandas, split

I would like some help weeding out a bit of data within a very long strings within only one column.  Within these long strings are bits of data separated by spaces. However, some extra characters (on certain row/indexes) are being found between needed information. I have put together a dataframe sample to show what is happening.

What is happening: The last line in code will cycle through the series and separate the first value between the beginning of string to the first space occurrence. Then move the value to a new_col. It is cycling through each row capturing '1' in some rows and random characters in other rows.

What I would like to have happen: Rows that begin with '1' leave alone. Rows that begin with anything other than '1' move to new column.  This will allow me to realign my data and correct spaces until the next hiccup. Hopefully, I can take away what I learn here and press forward.

What I have tried to do: I have tried to breakdown the problem with a for loop that will identify the 1st position as not a '1' goto the else statement and call the line to split data at first space. I receive a ValueError: Columns must be same length as key error at the line after the else statement.  I'm assuming that I'm trying to call to the dataframe column but the for loop is working from the variable "line". Just not sure.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series

file = {'Test': ['1 RTWXA LC WTHML',
                 '2TE7 1 RHRRA LY HGHRL',
                 '1 WJKFD LF LPKRF',
                 'ATEGR/5 1 WJFTA LC TRGEH',
                 '1 POKJD LD PLERT',
                 '4ARF/3 1 EDFRT TG IUYHT' ] }

df = pd.DataFrame(file)

# ----Questionable Code Starts-----
df[['new-col','Test']] = (df["Test"].str.extract("([^\s]*)\s?(1.*)"))
# ----Questionable Code Ends-------

# below line will split (using spaces) at one occurrence only.
# creates new column (misc_col) and places data within keeping row/index 
# integrity.
# df[['new_col','Test']] = df.Test.str.split(" ", 1, expand=True)

print(df)

What's Happening:                       What I would like:
           Test      new_col                           Test      new_col
0    RTWXA LC WTHML        1            0   1 RTWXA LC WTHML      
1  1 RHRRA LY HGHRL     2TE7            1   1 RHRRA LY HGHRL     2TE7 
2    WJKFD LF LPKRF        1            2   1 WJKFD LF LPKRF   
3  1 WJFTA LC TRGEH  ATEGR/5            3   1 WJFTA LC TRGEH     ATEGR/5
4    POKJD LD PLERT        1            4   1 POKJD LD PLERT      
5  1 EDFRT TG IUYHT   4ARF/3            5   1 EDFRT TG IUYHT     4ARF/3
```

As always, I appreciate any help you can provide to get me over this hump.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.Series.str.extract`:

```
print (df["Test"].str.extract("([^\s]*)\s?(1.*)"))

         0                 1
0           1 RTWXA LC WTHML
1     2TE7  1 RHRRA LY HGHRL
2           1 WJKFD LF LPKRF
3  ATEGR/5  1 WJFTA LC TRGEH
4           1 POKJD LD PLERT
5   4ARF/3  1 EDFRT TG IUYHT
```

Comment: Thanks Henry Yik for responding to my issue.  I was a bit confused by the columns 0, 1 shown in your example but re-worked your code into what I needed. I edited the code above to show this. Tested and working fine.  I will need to read up on how this pd.Series.str.extract works.  It looks bit like the regex statements. I appreciate your help with this.  Thanks